# How to import taxonomy from Json format

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

I have taxonomy in Json file. I need import this file into Drupal into exist vocabulary.how can I import data from Json file to exist vocabulary?

Comment: What version? Regardless, there is MIgrate Framework for Drupal 7 and the core migrate stuff in Drupal 8. Start there.

Comment: Sorry for mistake, json

Comment: Drupal 7. Migrate It's module? Should be write a code? Or it have needed interface for this goal?

Comment: Yes you would have to write a migration to import them in either case. I don't know if there is a module that will do it specifically for a json file. Some would say use Feeds, but I have no experience with Feeds.

Comment: Would you be able to edit the question and give a sample of the json? And is it flat or hierarchical data?

Comment: ok, publish later this file. Data will be hierarchical. And i can public there results my work. Will it be true?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources if you opt to use Migrate Framework in 7.x to do this (which is how I would personally approach it).

- https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate
- https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_source_json
- https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus

There are examples in Migrate/Migrate Plus on getting it setup. It looks like migrate_source_json was deprecated in favor of migrate_plus, but I included it for any historical references in it's issue queue.

There is probably a solution via Feeds as well but as stated, I am not experienced with Feeds.

If you can convert your format to CSV, there is also this one off module, [Taxonomy CSV](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Taxonomy Manager module](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager), it give you very  good features to work with taxonomies.

Description from module's page :

> This module provides a powerful interface for managing taxonomies. A
>   vocabulary gets displayed in a dynamic tree view, where parent terms
>   can be expanded to list their nested child terms or can be collapsed.
>
> The Taxonomy Manager has following operations and key features:
>
> ```
> dynamic treeview
> mass deleting
> mass adding of new terms
> moving of terms in hierarchies
> merging of terms (using the Term merge module in 7.x)
> fast weight changing with up and down arrows (and AJAX saving)
> AJAX powered term editing form
> simple search interface
> CSV Export of terms
> i18n support for multilingual vocabularies (per language terms)
> Double Tree interface for moving terms in hierarchies, adding new translations and switching terms between different vocabularies
> ```
>
> For using the Taxonomy Manager you should have JavaScript and
>   automatically load of images enabled in your browser.

**And about solution for what you asked:**

with getting help from https://json-csv.com/ | https://konklone.io/json/  ( or another one from plenty Json to CSV convertor) convert your Json terms to CSV  then import them with Taxonomy Manager with copy/paste CSV result on taxonomy import option.

Also you can import from CSV with [Taxonomy CSV module.](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv)